# Small ceiling brackets

Tags: brackets

I need to find a way to insert small ceiling brackets in a text, but I don't find any command to do it.
I'd need the brackets to look like the ones in the second line around MES  and MU.36:

[image]

I tried with \textuperscript{\lceil{MES}} but it doesn't work (btw I am pretty sure I am also mistaking the brackets {} placement here), it gives the whole text as superscript.

I am attaching my MWE with my preamble: I copied the brackets from the database I am using for the text but they do not show up in the pdf.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-verbose,latinemph,singletitle=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\pretolerance=10000
\tolerance=2000 
\emergencystretch=10pt


%%%%

%%%%

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} %INTERLINEA

%%%%

\DeclareLanguageMapping{italian}{italian-philosophy} %MAPPING LINGUA





%%%%%

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

%%%%

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\italianfont[Script=Latin]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Gentium Plus}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguages{greek}
\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false} %NO INDENT PRIMA RIGA DOPO CHAPTER O SECTION


%%%%



%%%%%%%

\usepackage{blindtext}   
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}


\makeatletter

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\iffootnote{\usebibmacro{cite:init}}{}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \iffootnote
     {\global\booltrue{cbx@mlafootnotes}%
      \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:mla:foot}}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:mla}}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{mla:foot:postnote}}

\makeatother


%%%%%%
\bibliography{contratti.bib}

%%%%%

\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}

%%%%%

\setlength{\parindent}{24pt}    %INDENT PARAGRAFI


%%%%%%
%TOGLIE "" AI TITOLI DI TUTTE LE ENTRY
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} 


%%%%%%%

%TOGLIE PARENTESI A DATE
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}% NEW
%  \printtext[parens]{% DELETED
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
%       \usebibmacro{date}}}% DELETED
       \usebibmacro{date}}% NEW
  \newunit}

%%%%%%

%TOGLIE "P." ALLE PAGINE DI TUTTE LE ENTRY
\DeclareFieldFormat*{pages}{#1}

%%%%%%%
\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \ifsingletitle{\usebibmacro{cite:opcit}}{%
    \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
      \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
      \iftoggle{cbx:commacit}{\setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
      {\setunit{\addspace\midsentence}}}}}

\usepackage{amstext}
\newcommand{\textunderscript}[1]{$_{\text{#1}}$} %underscript per numeri accadico

\begin{document}

MU.37.KAM\textsubscript{2} man-ti u mse-lu ITU.ŠE 9 LU\textsubscript{2}.mu-ma-'i-ir 
KUR URI.KI u LU\textsubscript{2}.paq-du. ⸢MEŠ⸣  
ša\textsubscript{2} LUGAL ša\textsubscript{2} ina ⸢MU.36⸣.KAM\textsubscript{2} ana KUR sa-par-du ana 
UGU LUGAL GIN-uʾ

\end{document}
```

Comment: Aren't `\lceil` a math symbol? Thus cannot be used in text mode. Also "does not work" is not very information. Please cite the exact error.

Comment: Off-topic: While loading the `geometry` package, instead of `top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm`, consider writing `margin=1.5cm`. Much more succinct, isn't it? Separately, since you use biblatex and Biber, consider replacing `\bibliography{contratti.bib}` with `\addbibresource{contratti.bib}`.

Comment: @daleif I did not remember that \lceil was a math symbol, I do not use symbols often. I also tried to use it between $$ but with this the brackets do not show up. As for "it does not work" I meant that if I use \textsuperscript{\lceil{MES}} the brackets do show (not as small as I need them) but the whole text is superscripted.

Comment: No, `\textsuperscript{\lceil{MES}} ` will give you an error, don't just ignore errors. I get the error `Missing $ inserted`

Comment: @daleif thank you, I rewrote is as it follows: ` \textsuperscript{$\ceil$}MES ` and the bracket appears. It was just the $ missing, as you said.

Answer (score 3):

The delimiters are named upper-right/left-corner:

`\ulcorner` and `\urcorner`

from the package `amssymb`

Stumbled across on: https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your answer might be more helpful to the OP and other, future readers if you also posted some code to show you would use `\ulcorner` and `\urcorrner` to solve the formatting problem at hand.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses the `amsmath` (`\ensuremath` and `\text`), `amssymb` (for `\lceil` and `\rceil`), and `bm` (for `\bm`) packages to create a macro called `\ceilbrackets`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for "\textcolor" macro
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm}
\newcommand\ceilbrackets[1]{\ensuremath{%
   {}^{\scriptscriptstyle\bm{\lceil}}\mkern-1mu%
   \text{#1}%
   {}^{\scriptscriptstyle\bm{\rceil}}}}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{blue}{\ceilbrackets{ME\v S}}, \ceilbrackets{MU.36}
\end{document}
```